# Firebase getting url after image upload

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have an application where I want to upload two images , one is a normal image and the second is a thumbnail. I am ignoring the thumbnail for now and only focusing on the main image. The steps I am working on are the following:

Step 1 : Upload image
Step 2 : Get Download link as string 
Step 3 : Add download link to real time database in firebase

I am stuck on step 2
I have done the following :

```
 else if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                {
                    Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                    File thumb_filePath = new File(resultUri.getPath());
                    Bitmap thumb_bitmap = null;
                    try {
                        thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(this)
                                .setMaxWidth(200)
                                .setMaxHeight(200)
                                .setQuality(75)
                                .compressToBitmap(thumb_filePath);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                    final byte[] thumb_byte = baos.toByteArray();

                    final StorageReference mStorageThumbPathRef = mStorageRef.child("chatappthumbimg").child(current_userid + ".jpg");
                    final StorageReference mStoragePathRef = mStorageRef.child("chatappimg").child(current_userid + ".jpg");


                    UploadTask uploadTask;
                    uploadTask = mStoragePathRef.putFile(resultUri);

                    Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                throw task.getException();
                            }

                            // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                            return mStoragePathRef.getDownloadUrl();
                        }
                    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                            } else {
                                // Handle failures
                                // ...
                            }
                        }
                    });







                }


            }

        }
```

And I used the documentation for help : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

However, now I am unsure how to proceed.
Does mStoragePathRef.getDownloadUrl(); gives me back the real url of the image?
Because upon some earlier tests I got some kind of task and not an image url

Comment: I can't speak for the Android side of things - I live in the Web portion of Firebase... but I imagine they have similar experiences. From my experience you are correct... it does not return the actual URL. In JavaScript it returns an "observable" that eventually gives us the URL... I'd give you an example of how I get the finished URL, but I doubt that would be much help in your Android-world.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyW I would be glad to take a look

Comment: https://androidjson.com/retrieve-stored-images-firebase-storage/ thank me later

Answer (score 1):

Per comments above, OP requested to see the way I address uploads in my project - which is unfortunately not Android. I don't expect this will help much since this isn't the right language, but take whatever you can from it.

Specifically, this is done in Angular 6 using the AngularFire2 package. I included the complete function for reference, but the relevant portion is towards the end, talking about `this.downloadURLObservable` and `this.downloadURLSubscription$`

```
// Uploads file to Firebase storage, and returns the file's access URL
pushUpload(pageName, upload) {
  // Returns a promise, so we can use .then() when pushUpload is called
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

    this.uploadPercent = 0;

    // Include the current timeStamp in the file name, so each upload can be uniquely identified - no 1 photo will ever be used in 2 places, can safely delete this file later w/o fear of messing up something else
    const timeStamp = new Date().getTime();

    // Upload the file
    const uploadTask = this.afStorage.upload(`${pageName}/${timeStamp}-${upload.file.name}`, upload.file);

    // Observe percentage changes
    this.uploadPercentObservable = uploadTask.percentageChanges();
    this.uploadPercentageSubscription$ = this.uploadPercentObservable.subscribe(
      eachValue => {
        this.uploadPercent = Math.round(eachValue*10) / 10
      },
      err => {
        console.log('uploadPercentageSubscription$ errored out in upload.service.ts, here is the err:')
        console.log(err)
      },
      () => {
        console.log('uploadPercentageSubscription$ completed')
      }
    )

    // Get notified when the download URL is available, return it from the function
    uploadTask.snapshotChanges().pipe( finalize( () => {
      this.downloadURLObservable = this.afStorage.ref(`${pageName}/${timeStamp}-${upload.file.name}`).getDownloadURL()
      this.downloadURLSubscription$ = this.downloadURLObservable.subscribe(
        eachValue => {
          resolve(eachValue)
        },
        err => {
          console.log('downloadURLSubscription$ errored out in upload.service..ts, here is the err:')
          console.log(err)
        },
        () => {
          console.log('downloadURLSubscription$ completed')
        }
      )
    })).subscribe()

  }); // End of returned promise
} // End of pushUpload() for regular image
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might be stuck at the same thing , Uri downloadUri = task.getResult(); is the one that has the real download url